# aws elastic beans container commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-2.4, elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to copy Apache server setup file wsgi.conf to httpd/conf.d folder when deploying myapp via elastic beanstalk. However, after deployment, if I sftp to httpd/conf.d I don't see my file.

myapp folder structure:

```
myapp/
- .ebextension
--- configuration.conf
- folderx
- foldery
- wsgi.conf
```

in the configuration.conf file i have the following:

```
container_commands:
  04_wsgireplace:
    command: "cp ../wsgi.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf"
```

after deployment, in the eb deployment logs I see success for the copy command.

1. are the relative paths I'm using correct?
2. what am I doing wrong?

PS. What I want to achieve is set a rewrite rule for http --> https re-directions. Is there an alternative solution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could find something more official, but I did find several references ([1](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=182431),[2](https://rickchristianson.wordpress.com/2013/11/02/updating-wsgi-automatically-in-amazon-aws/)) to folks using something like this:

```
container_commands:
  04_wsgireplace:
    command: "cp wsgi.conf ../wsgi.conf"
```

or

```
container_commands:
  04_wsgireplace:
    command: "cp .ebextensions/wsgi.conf ../wsgi.conf"
```

It depends on where in your project you've stored `wsgi.conf`, I assume.  I'm about to try it myself (for a flask project), and I'll report back!

Update: I tried it out (with wsgi.conf in .ebextensions), and it worked (for me).